# Error: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all(). Unable to update dataframe column

Tags: python, dataframe

I have a dataframe `df` that has following values:

```
           activityType activity_preferance
userID      
agashi1996  joinClub    Nan
agashi1998  post        Nan
agashi1998  post        Nan
agashi1998  post        Nan
agashi1994  followuser  Nan
```

The `userID` column is the index here.

I want to fill the column `activity_preferance` with 1,2 and 3 if `activityType` is `joinClub`, `post`, `followuser` respectively.

I wrote this code:

```
for i,row in df_activity_filter.iterrows():
    if (df_activity_filter.loc[i,'activityType'] == 'joinClub'):
        df_activity_filter.loc[i,'activity_preferance'] = 1
    elif (df_activity_filter.loc[i,'activityType'] == 'post'):
        df_activity_filter.loc[i,'activity_preferance'] = 2
    elif (df_activity_filter.loc[i,'activityType'] == 'followuser'):
        df_activity_filter.loc[i,'activity_preferance'] = 3
```

I am getting the error:

`ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().`

The desired dataframe/output should be like this:

```
           activityType activity_preferance
userID      
agashi1996  joinClub    1
agashi1998  post        2
agashi1998  post        2
agashi1998  post        2
agashi1994  followuser  3
```

Any help on this?

Comment: Please check the performance timings of my solution vs all others in my post. Mine is at least 5-10 times faster.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Loops are really slow**. You should use [`numpy.select`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.select.html) here:

```
In [1577]: import numpy as np

In [1578]: conditions = [df.activityType == 'joinClub', df.activityType == 'post', df.activityType == 'followuser']

In [1579]: choices = [1, 2, 3]

In [1580]: df['activity_preferance'] = np.select(conditions, choices)

In [1581]: df
Out[1581]: 
           activityType  activity_preferance
userID                                      
agashi1996     joinClub                    1
agashi1998         post                    2
agashi1998         post                    2
agashi1998         post                    2
agashi1994   followuser                    3
```

#### Performance comparison with other solutions:

My solution:

```
In [1582]: %timeit np.select(conditions, choices)
45.5 µs ± 1.84 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

@Djib2011's solution:

```
In [1584]: %timeit df['activityType'].map(mapping)
401 µs ± 5.09 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

@JenilDave's solution:

```
In [1590]: %timeit df.activityType.replace({'joinClub':1,'post':2,'followuser':3})
490 µs ± 20.6 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

@yashjain's solution:

```
In [1585]: %timeit df['activityType'].apply(lambda x: 1 if x=='joinClub' else None)
114 µs ± 1.56 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

Comment: No Doubt your solution is great but it requires lot of Hardcoding

Comment: Not a `lot` of typing. But, I guess I'll take better performance over writing any day.

Comment: Yes, better performance always wins if there is not development time and memory constraints

Answer (score 1):

Mayank provided quite a nice answer still you can explore pandas `apply` method

```
df_activity_filter['activity_preferance'] = df['activityType'].apply(lambda x: 1 if x=='joinClub' else None)
df_activity_filter['activity_preferance'] = df['activityType'].apply(lambda x: 2 if x=='post' else None)

and similarly others...
```

Answer (score 1):

**th;dr** I think what you actually want is to map the values of `"activityType"` to integers. This is better done by the ['map' method of pd.Series](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html).

```py
mapping = {'joinClub': 1, 'post': 2, 'followuser': 3}
df['activity_preferance'] = df['activityType'].map(mapping)
```

---

What the error means is that if you have a series (`ser`) like this:

```
>>> print(ser)

0  True
1  False
2  True
3  True
4  False
...
```

its truth value might be ambiguous (i.e. is it True or False?). What should python do if I were to write:

```py
if ser:
   # do something
```

There is no clear answer, because the boolean evaluation of `ser` is ambiguous, so it raises an error.

Comment: `map` is really slow when compared to `np.select`. Please check my solution for timing comparisons.

Comment: @MayankPorwal yes you are right yours is much faster, however if you aren't that concerned about performance I would prefer map due to it being conceptually simpler and more clean...

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you try this, using [df.replace](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html)

Creating column 'activity_preferance' from 'activityType'

```py
>>> df['activity_preferance'] = (df['activityType']).copy()
```

Then we will replace the 'activity_preferance' columns values with your condition.

```py
>>> (df['activity_preferance']).replace({'joinClub':1,'post':2,'followuser':3},inplace=True)
```

Note: Be carefull with the `inplace=True`